# Как правильно задать задание CRON

Tags: cron

Есть путь `~/site.beget.tech/public_html/tmp`
Мне нужно чтобы содержимое папки `tmp` удалялось каждые 3 часа, но при этом папка `tmp` не удалялась. Подскажите пожалуйста команду.

Comment: Чем не устраивает `rm -rf ~/site.beget.tech/public_html/tmp/*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
0 3 * * * rm -rf ~/site.beget.tech/public_html/tmp/*
```

Приведенный выше код означает, что каждые 3 часа вы удаляете все файлы в указанном вами пути. Пожалуйста, обратитесь к этой ссылке для получения дополнительной информации о Cron: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Спасибо большое